# Open e-mail client with attachment file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to open my email client (for example Outlook) with the following:

```
<a href="mailto:name1@rapidtables.com?subject=Assundo email&body=Email body">
Send mail </a>
```

Now I wanted to send an attachment through `mailto`. I have already seen that it is not possible with the `mailto` function, but is there another way to open my email client with an attachment? Is there any alternative to `mailto` for this purpose?

Comment: @GhostGambler, I've seen it, but that's why I'm asking if there are alternatives to mailto

Comment: @pc_oc -- of course, these would likely be backend services.

Comment: Not in a browser there isn't.